# Set batch size using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I need to perform a batch insert of 1kk+ rows using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in Spring jdbc.
So my code is like this:

```
public void insert(Collection<Person> entities) {
    SqlParameterSource[] params = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(entities.toArray());
    namedJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertSql, params);
}
```

Actually I use batch insert for 5 different tables which are related. So the problem here, that if I insert about 1kk rows for on of these tables, the app. tries to insert them a lot of times and after gives me OutOfMemoryError. 
I think it's because I didn't provide a batch size value (kinda a portion of rows of provided collection of total rows which will be commited after insertion), but I don't know how to set this parameter through my NamedParameterJdbcTemplate value.

Or maybe there are other suggestions how it can be accomplished ?

thx

UPDATED: I use SimpleDataSource and DataSourceTransactionManager in my configuration

UPDATED: I tried to use SingleConnectionDataSource and called method setAutoCommit(false). Then, after batchUpdate of 100k rows in code above I called:

```
try {
            ((JdbcTemplate)  dbTemplate.getJdbcOperations()).getDataSource().getConnection().commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

}
```

and it works better but this is not good for me using such code. Maybe there is another better solution ? And for 1kk rows it still says that not enought memory to perform batchUpdate.

Comment: I tried do batch insert using plain JDBC for 100k rows and it did it for 7 seconds. I just disabled autocommit, created prepared statement, and used iterator adding batch and inserting every 1k rows. After that I  commited all changes.  So how can i get same result using Spring jdbc features ?

Comment: BTW, I tried to use BatchSqlUpdate setting batch size, but according log info, it always created me a new connection after each executeBatch() statement: DEBUG [main] (SimpleDriverDataSource.java:138):: Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName. Maybe I made bad configurations for spring jdbc (for datasource and transaction mngr.) ?